# How can I change the alignment of pagenumbers of TOC using documentclass{scrbook}?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm using a template I've found and now I would like to change the Table Of Contents. I'm using the following document class.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
```

And the following is said about the TOC:

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\tableofcontents
```

The outcome is:
[image: TOC]

What can I do to align the page numbers on the right of the page?
And how can I remove the page numbers of the parts (Introduction & Conceptual Design)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcme, that is the layout decision you chose by using classicthesis. If you don't like the visual appearance, do not use classicthesis. Without it, you can just as well (maybe better) write up a thesis (bachelor, master, dissertation, ...).

Comment: You should provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) or otherwise...

Comment: `dottedtoc` and smile

Comment: And something like `\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\phantom}` to remove the page numbers of the parts from the TOC.

Comment: Thank you! By adding dottedtoc and \renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\phantom} I got what I wanted!

Comment: @esdd Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use option `dottedtoc` for package `classicthesis` to align the page numbers on the right hand side of the page  as suggested by Johannes_B in a comment.

Package `classicthesis` uses package `tocloft` to format the TOC. So you can add something like

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\phantom}
```

to remove the page numbers of the parts in TOC. Or better - as suggested by @PhilipPirrip in a comment -

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Note that the package `tocloft` has this command to turn the part page numbers off: `\cftpagenumbersoff{part} `